# display iso-8859-1 encoded data gives strange characters

Tags: ruby, encoding, csv

I have a ISO-8859-1 encoded csv-file that I try to open and parse with ruby:

```
require 'csv'

filename = File.expand_path('~/myfile.csv')
file = File.open(filename, "r:ISO-8859-1")
CSV.parse(file.read, col_sep: "\t") do |row| 
  puts row 
end
```

If I leave out the encoding from the call to File.open, I get an error

> ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

My problem is that the call to `puts row` displays strange characters instead of the norwegian characters æ,ø,å:

> BOKF�RINGSDATO

I get the same if I open the file in textmate, forcing it to use UTF-8 encoding.

By assigning the file content to a string, I can check the encoding used for the string. As expected, it shows ISO-8859-1.

So when I `puts` each row, why does it output the string as UTF-8?
Is it something to do with the csv-library?

I use ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Your code works fine here (Ruby 1.9.2 on ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found myself an answer by trying different things from the documentation:

```
require 'csv'

filename = File.expand_path('~/myfile.csv')
File.open(filename, "r:ISO-8859-1") do |file|
  CSV.parse(file.read.encode("UTF-8"), col_sep: "\t") do |row| 
    #                    ↳  returns a copy transcoded to UTF-8.
    puts row 
  end
end
```

As you can see, all I have done, is to encode the string to an UTF-8 string before the CSV-parser gets it.

---

**Edit:**
Trying this solution on macruby-head, I get the following error message from encode( ):

> Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xD8" on UTF-8

Even though I specify encoding when opening the file, macruby use UTF-8.
This seems to be an known macruby limitation: [Encoding is always UTF-8](http://www.macruby.org/trac/ticket/742)

Comment: From my experience there are few times that decoding/encoding goes smoothly when dealing with a file for the first time. It's enough to make me tear my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Iconv to convert the file contents to UTF-8 before parsing?

Comment: maybe I could, but it would be better if the application could read the file as they are.

Answer (score 0):

ISO-8859-1 and Win-1252 are reaallly close in their character sets. Could some app have processed the file and converted it? Or could it have been received from a machine that was defaulting to Win-1252, which is Window's standard setting?

Software that senses the code-set can get the encoding wrong if there are no characters in the 0x80 to 0x9F byte-range so you might try setting `file = File.open(filename, "r:ISO-8859-1")` to `file = File.open(filename, "r:Windows-1252")`. (I think "Windows-1252" is the right encoding name.)

I used to write spiders, and HTML is notorious for being mis-labeled or for having encoded binary characters from one character set embedded in another. I used some bad language many times over these problems several years ago, before most languages had implemented UTF-8 and Unicode so I understand the frustration.

[ISO/IEC_8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), 
[Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Comment: If there's uncertainty about what character set the original file is, there's a gem called rchardet which you can use to detect the source's character set.

Comment: In my experience it wasn't accurate enough. There are some text runs that defy categorization because they are a mix. When decoding RSS feeds I used to encounter HTML embedded in CDATA blocks that had HTML encoded characters using &#nnnn; format which would decode to who knows what.

Comment: Windows-1252 makes no difference.

Comment: At that point I'd dive in to find out exactly what the bytes are, and if they map to single or multi-byte characters that you'd expect in that string. That might tell you what encoding to use. After all that, it's possible you have the right encoding and those characters don't belong at all because someone injected bytes using `<ALT>` plus their number pad.

Comment: Ø is represented by \xD8, Æ by \xC6 it that tells you anything.